# division in kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I have two integer variables which I need to divide in order to work the percentage out for something. I have (variablea / variableb) * 100. The problem is that the (variablea / variableb) will be between 0 and 1 so it gets rounded to 0 because it is an int. How can I get round this so the answer isn't always 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `(variablea * 100) / variableb`.

This will truncate the result. If you're rather round to the *nearest* whole percent, you could do `(variablea * 100 + variableb/2) / variableb`.

Finally, instead of `100` you could use a constant such as `1000` or `10000` if you'd like to get more decimal places (just remember to format the number correctly when printing, i.e. scale it by `10` or `100`).

Comment: Or even `variablea * 10000 / variableb` and regard the result as 100 times a percentage.  For example, if displaying it, `printf ("result is %d.%02d percent", result / 100, result % 100);`